# Lilypond inserting bars at wrong place

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond

I find that lilypond routinely inserts bars at wrong places and does not even warn about it. e.g. Consider this:

```
{                                                                                   
  \time 4/4                                                                         
  \tempo 4 = 100                                                                    
  \relative c' {                                                                    
    e32 fis32 g32 a32 b8 c4 b32 c2 d32 e32 fis16                                    
  }                                                                                 
}
```

Lilypond produces this:

[image]

There should not be a bar after C2. In fact the only way to insert a bar is to split the C2 note and use ties:

```
{                                                                                
  \time 4/4                                                                      
  \tempo 4 = 100                                                                 
  \relative c' {                                                                 
    e32 fis32 g32 a32 b8 c4 b32 c4..~ c32~ | c32 d32 e32 fis16                   
  }                                                                              
}
```

The documentation is very sparse on this aspect. Is there a way to get lilypond to at least warn about the error? It would be awesome if lilypond could auto correct as well!

Comment: Is this what you need? https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/displaying-rhythms#automatic-note-splitting

Comment: A life saver!! Please write it as an answer. I will accept. Lilypond documentation is a mess. Very difficult to figure out what is where.

Comment: @user1079505 For my example lilypond produced 3 dots. Is there any setting to limit the number of dots ?

Comment: But I don't have much idea about lilypond... I just figured that this first bar is too long, and realized you expected the half note to be split, and somehow found it. Perhaps someone with more lilypond expertise can explain it better.

Comment: Re "LilyPond documentation is a mess": have you tried the index? If you go to https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/lilypond-index.html and Control-F for "split", you find what you want instantly...

Comment: That bar line isn't wrong. Your input is self-contradictory in a way that makes it impossible to render bar lines in a consistent way (and Lilypond will warn you about this if you use bar annotations in your source, which you should).

Answer (score 4):

Lilypond is not a magic machine. It won't try to second-guess what you meant. Quite the opposite: it will do exactly what you tell it to do.

If you say `\time 4/4`, then it will put a barline every four quarter-notes, no matter what notes are used. In this case, that falls "in the middle" of the half-note, so there is a barline and some part of the note length overflows into the next bar. The placement of the barlines is purely automatic and it has nothing to do whatsoever with where you put the `|` symbols.

The `|` symbols fulfill another role: they're *bar checks*. If you use them, Lilypond will check whether the bars coincide with the bar checks exactly, and you get a warning for any that do not match.

For instance, in your first code snippet, I have no idea where you wanted the barline to occur, because your half note is 1/32 too long. But if you used the `|` symbol at that place, Lilypond would warn you.

In the second code snippet, everything works out, because you replaced a half-note with a double-dotted quarter note and a 1/32 note, which is only 7/4 × 1/4 + 1/32 = 15/32 in total, so it's exactly that 1/32 less than the half note. Lilypond will find that it is putting the barline exactly where you have put the `|`, and it doesn't complain.

Finally: I don't know what documentation you are reading, but I would suggest starting with the [Learning manual](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/learning/index). Coincidentally, this matter is the very first thing explained in the manual (if we don't take installation instructions into account).

Not sure if this gives the answer you wanted. If not, feel free to write a comment and I'll try to modify it to be more helpful.

Comment: Automatic note splitting is exactly what I was looking for. What' s the point of using a tool if I have to do these things manually?  I think putting the bar after c2 without any warning is not correct.

Comment: First, notes extending over bar lines are found in Renaissance music scores, and second, it is much more difficult than you'd think to guess how to do the splitting reliably.

Comment: @kargirwar I mean in that case it's a effect that you do want, but chances are also there that it isn't. Like suppose you added an extra note somewhere by accident hold a note for longer or shorter than expected and as Lilypond can't tell your intentions, it breaks apart a half note that should actually be a half note. You wouldn't get an error it's just all wrong and your focus might be on the split half note not realizing what caused it. While if everything remains as is and you get a warning that there are too many notes in a bar, you might have an easier time debugging that.

Comment: The automatic split thing is working wondefully well for me , so no issues really.

Comment: Uh, "works in the score I have tested it on" and "satisfies the needs of everyone without surprising anyone" are really different things.